# Excel cell formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to insert numbers in an Excel cell (ex. 01-00), but the formatting wants it to default to a date (ex. Jan-1).  How do I delete this formating so I can enter simple numbers?

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible ways:

1) format your cells as text **before** input

2) use an apostrophe to precede the entry, e.g. enter '01-00 - the apostrophe tells excel that the entry is to be treated as text - it isn't displayed

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an option to prevent Excel from auto-formatting dates, but here are a few workarounds you can try before entering data:

#### Changing the Normal Style (only for Excel 2007 and above)

Do this before entering any values or data into your spreadsheet.

1. Under the **Home** Tab, go to the **Styles** section and right-click the **Normal** style.
2. Click **Modify** and then **Format**.
3. Select **Text** under the **Number** tab, or use the custom number format mentioned below. Click **Ok**.

This way, you don't have to reformat cells/worksheets that you might add.

---

#### Custom Number Format ("00-00")

[image]

To set it up:

1. Select the cells you'd like to format.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.
3. Go to Number > Custom.
4. Enter `00-00` into the **Type** field.

After setting up the number format, you just have to type the numbers without the dash (i.e. `0100`, `0213`) and Excel will automatically format it to show `01-00` or `02-13`.

Note that Excel will treat the values as they are entered.